# Can't display two different calls to the screen right after each other

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

If I run the following two commands at the same time only the first one displays.  If I run them separately then I get both results. What am I missing?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Computername "Your Server Name" | select driveletter, BlockSize, FreeSpace

Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}' -and $_.Version -gt 3.5 -and $_.Version -lt 3.6} | Select PSChildName, Version, Release;
```

Comment: The default formatter doesn't handle the disparate objects. Append `| Out-String` to both if you intend to run them one after the other in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before.  You're confusing PowerShell's output table display.  It's a bug with `Select-Object`, as far as I know.  Here's some sample code:

```
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="1";e={1}};
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="2";e={2}};
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="1";e={11}},@{n="2";e={22}};
```

Which outputs (whitespace condensed):

```
 1
 -
 1

11
```

While this code:

```
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="1";e={11}},@{n="2";e={22}};
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="1";e={1}};
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="2";e={2}};
```

Outputs this (whitespace condensed):

```
 1   2
 -   -
11  22
 1    
     2
```

Notice it's all in one table?  It's like the first `Select-Object` determines the table's headers, and the rest have to follow suit.  I don't know why it does it or if it's been fixed in PowerShell v5.0.

The easy workaround is to pipe to `Format-Table`:

```
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="1";e={1}} | Format-Table -AutoSize;
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="2";e={2}} | Format-Table -AutoSize;
"" | Select-Object -Property @{n="1";e={11}},@{n="2";e={22}} | Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

Which correctly outputs:

```
1
-
1


2
-
2


 1  2
 -  -
11 22
```